# Calling Php script from reactjs giving Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs

I want to make an ajax call to php scripts.
I also tried using handleSubmit(event) for making a call. It didn't work. Then I tried ajax call. To resolve this error I also gave

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

in my .htaccess file.Still I'm getting the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="./">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="CoreUI - Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="Łukasz Holeczek">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Bootstrap,Admin,Template,Open,Source,jQuery,CSS,HTML,RWD,Dashboard">


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());
      // Shared ID
      gtag('config', 'UA-118965717-3');
      // Bootstrap ID
      gtag('config', 'UA-118965717-5');


var resp = "";
var htmlstring = "";
var template = "";
var testIDArray = [];
var testPlanNameArray = [];
var errorArray = [];
var errorArraySecond = [];
var historyErrorDescArray = [];
var domain = "CERT";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Analyse").click(function() 
  {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/INSTA/home.php',
        success: function(response) 
        {
          resp = response;
          // alert(resp);   
          $.get("http://localhost/INSTA/new.php?&filename=" + resp).done(function(data1) {
            htmlstring = data1;

            $('<div />', {
              html: htmlstring
              }).find('div').each(function() 
              {
                if($(this).is(':contains("FAIL")'))
                {          
                  if($(this).find("table tr:first td:first").text() == "Test ID")
                  {
                    testIDArray.push($(this).find("table tr:first td:eq(2)").text().trim());
                  }  
                  if($(this).find("table tr:eq(1) td:first").text() == "Test Plan Name")
                  {
                    testPlanNameArray.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                  }
                  if($(this).find("table tr:eq(12) td:first").text() == "Error")
                  {
                    errorArray.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(12) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                  }
                  if($(this).find("table tr:eq(16) td:first").text() == "History Error Description")
                    historyErrorDescArray.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(16) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                    else 
                    historyErrorDescArray.push("");
                  if($(this).find("table tr:eq(15) td:first").text() == "Error")
                  {
                    errorArraySecond.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(15) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                  }
                  else
                  {                   
                      if($(this).find("table tr:eq(18) td:first").text() == "Error")
                    errorArraySecond.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(18) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                    else 
                    errorArraySecond.push("");
                  }
                }
              })
            // alert(errorArraySecond);  
            // alert(testIDArray);
              $.get("http://localhost/INSTA/dbValidation.php?&testIDArray=" + testIDArray + "&testPlanNameArray=" + testPlanNameArray + "&errorArray=" + errorArray + "&historyErrorDescArray=" + historyErrorDescArray + "&errorArraySecond=" + errorArraySecond ).done(function(data3) {

                    alert(data3);
              });
          });
        }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
  </head>
  <body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed sidebar-lg-show">


<select>
  <option value="Eligibility">Eligibility</option>

</select> 
<button  class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="Analyse" >Analyse</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

is my code. I'm trying to call php scripts by making ajax calls. I'm getting

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

error. Kindly help how will I resolve this error.

Comment: do those headers come in the response? check the response headers in your browser developer tools network tab

Comment: No I didn't get any headers in the response.

Comment: `Still I'm getting the same error` vs `I got an additional error` ... which is it, the same or additional ... I can guarantee without those CORS headers you won't get far ... now, put them back in, and what is this additional error

Comment: No I got some additional error because of some other mistake. After adding CORS I'm still getting the error which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: but are you getting those headers in the browser - if not, you're doing something else wrong

Comment: Yes I'm getting those errors in the console

Comment: I asked if you can see HEADERS not ERRORS

Comment: No I'm not able to see headers

Comment: perhaps your apache config is wrong then